# Data exchange between two application (need patterns)

Tags: integration, architecture

Application "A":  Web application. Data exchange via web-services.
Application "B": Windows application. Data exchange via COM.
Are there patterns or best practices to implement integration between these applications?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand you, can't B exchange data with A through A webservices ?

Comment: Yes, of course, but I try to find something like [this](http://www.eaipatterns.com/), but not Enterprise.

Comment: As long as webservices are already involved, the webservices should be the pattern. So App B must be changed to be webservice client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so any pattern  you will be use it for communication among these application.

For webservice design and communication this will help you ....

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954638.aspx